# Weird output with a variable length array?

Tags: c, gcc, variable-length-array

I am breaking my head on this but cannot proceed so please help.
Working on a programming assignment:

```
INPUT:
First line contains a value N representing the dimension of the input matrix, followed by N lines, each line representing a row of the matrix. Within each row, N values are given and are separated by whitespace.
```

So instead of using fgets() and then extracting the digits using strtol() I am forced to use scanf() because the assignment platform does not work properly with strtol().

This is my program:

```
int main()
{
   int N;
   int arr[N][N];
   int idx1, idx2=0;

   scanf("%d ",&N);

   for (idx1=0; idx1<N; idx1++) {
      for(idx2=0; idx2<N; idx2++) {
         scanf("%d", &arr[idx1][idx2]);
         printf("arr[%d][%d]=%d ", idx1, idx2, arr[idx1][idx2]);
      }
   }
   printf("\n");
   for (idx1=0; idx1<N; idx1++) {
      for(idx2=0; idx2<N; idx2++) {
         printf("arr[%d][%d]=%d ", idx1, idx2, arr[idx1][idx2]);
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3
1 2 3
arr[0][0]=1 arr[0][1]=2 arr[0][2]=3 
4 5 6
arr[1][0]=4 arr[1][1]=5 arr[1][2]=6 
7 8 9
arr[2][0]=7 arr[2][1]=8 arr[2][2]=9 
arr[0][0]=1 arr[0][1]=4 arr[0][2]=7 arr[1][0]=4 arr[1][1]=7 arr[1][2]=8 arr[2][0]=7 arr[2][1]=8 arr[2][2]=9
```

FWIW gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

Why is the second output not matching the first? What am i missing here?

Comment: Why do you have a space after the conversion specifier in your scanf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int N;
int arr[N][N];
int idx1, idx2=0;

scanf("%d ",&N);
```

You have to declare `arr` after you write `N` object. Here when `arr` is declared, `N` value is indeterminate.

Comment: Thanks, had thought of that earlier but did not try it out earlier.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to create a variable length array like that, you need to dynamically allocate it instead of creating an array of size N (N has some garbage value at the time) and then changing the size of it based on user input.  Use malloc or calloc.

Comment: It's fine to get the user input and then create the array with `int arr[N][N]`.

Comment: The thing is, it's creating an array of size [N][N] where N hasn't been initialized, which from what I've learned, is terrible practice

Comment: Yes, but it is OK practice to initialize or assign N first and then create the array, as my comment suggests

Comment: int N;
int arr[N][N];

This is what I am talking about being bad practice, N has a garbage value and creating a 2D array off of that is bad practice, even if it changes later

Comment: We agree that `int N; int arr[N][N];` is bad practice. I am saying that it is OK practice to instead do `int N; scanf("%d", &N); int arr[N][N];` -- if we also include some error-checking that `N` was input correctly. As such, you don't need to use malloc.